# Twin the Divination Spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic, divination

Are you as a divine soul sorcerer able to [Twinned Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) [Divination](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/divination), and get into contact with multiple gods, and ask twice the amount of questions?

Comment: Ok I'm stupid. Thanks guys :) will accept an answer when I can.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### You cannot twin a spell with a range of self.

Twinned Spell states:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and **doesn't have a range of self**…

*Divination* has a range of self, so it is not eligible for use with Twinned Spell.

For reference, the *Sage Advice Compendium* has [a handy guide on the author’s intent for Twinned Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA244):

> #### Can my sorcerer use Twinned Spell to affect a particular spell?
>
> You can use Twinned Spell on a spell that …
>
> - targets only one creature
> - doesn’t have a range of self
> - is incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell’s current level
>
> If you know this rule yet are still unsure whether a particular spell qualifies for Twinned Spell, consult with your DM, who has the final say. If the two of you are curious about our design intent, here is the list of things that disqualify a spell for us:
>
> - The spell has a range of self.
> - The spell can target an object.
> - The spell allows you to choose more than one creature to be affected by it, particularly at the level you’re casting the spell. Some spells increase their number of potential targets when you cast them at a higher level.
> - The spell can force more than one creature to make a saving throw before the spell’s duration expires.
> - The spell lets you make a roll of any kind that can affect more than one creature before the spell’s duration expires

Comment: Wait, all spells that CAN target objects are disqualified?

Comment: @Hobbamok That is the intent of the designers, yes.

Answer (score 6):

### No

Twinned Spell says:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature **and doesn’t have a range of self**, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell

Divination has a range of self. Therefore, it can not be used with Twinned Spell.